# How to correct this regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to catch the regex like: `"cx001"` or `" cx001"` or `" cx001 "` or `"cx001."` or `"cx001,"` etc

now I'm trying with this regex:

```
"[^|\\s|>]*([a-z]{2}[0-9]+\\.?)\\b"
```

but I have a problem that is: `"#cx001"`, `"@cx001"` is matched too.

I want the regex to accept "space" or "start string" at first only!!!

Comment: Are you trying to capture the whole string? (whitespaces and all) or just the `cx001` portion of it (ultimately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You current regex misuses the starting anchor by placing it inside a character class `[]`. You can fix it like this:

```
(^|\s*)\b([a-z]{2}[0-9]+\.?)\b
```

Now your regex is explicit about the beginning of line, after which may follow zero or more whitespace characters.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/JTJ2Oz).

Comment: for string: "match my regex: cx1"
It's cannot catch "cx1"

Comment: @Cuder_VN Could you give a sample string that didn't match?

Comment: for string: "match my regex: cx1" It's cannot catch "cx1" 
so i put a character \ before your \ because in java it's a special character: 

my code in java: 

public static final String REGEX_HASHTAGS = "^\\s*([a-z]{2}[0-9]+\\.?)\\b";


Matcher matchers = Pattern.compile(IGovConstants.REGEX_HASHTAGS).matcher(inputValue);
while (matchers.find())
{
 //TODO
}

Comment: @Cuder_VN I did not realize that you wanted to allow other characters after the beginning of the string. Take a look at the update.

Comment: i don't know why when i try your regex with notepad++ it's OK but when i do it with Pattern-Matcher in Java, it's not work. It's OK for this string "aaaaaaaa123" too.

Comment: @Cuder_VN Please take a look at the demo I added.

Comment: woooowww, It's perfect now ^^!, thank you so much ^^!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `"\\b"`. Thats say must the string end with space. Was better `"\\b*"` or `"\\b?"`
* : 0 or many, ?: 0 or 1.

```
"\\s*[a-z]{2}[0-9]+[\\s\\.,]*"
```

`\\s*`: can beginn with space
`[a-z]{2}`: letter char exact 2 time
`[0-9]+`: number min=1 max=...
`[\\s\\.,]*`: space, point or comma min=0 or max=... combination.

Comment: thank for your help but still have the same problem:
The regex PASS for "aaaaaaaa123" too.

Comment: "\\s*cx[0-9]+[\\s\\.,]*"

Comment: "\\s*cx001[\\s\\.,]*" if cx001 is constant